# Limit db response to 5 rows

Tags: php, database

Starting from the following code, I need to just limit the results displayed to 5 author names, but keeping the same identical properties.

```
$value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'authors_names', true);
$value_array = explode(',', $value);
$num_values = count($value_array);
foreach ($value_array as $key => $array) {
    $remove_space = str_replace(' ', '-', $array);
    $url = esc_url('http://mywebsite.com/authors/' . $remove_space);
    if ('' !== $url) {
        $display = esc_html($array);
        print"<a href='$url'>$display</a>";
    }
    if ($key < $num_values - 1) {
        echo ',';
    };
}
```

I'm trying like this, but there seem not to work...
Where am I going wrong?

```
$mpirate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'authors_names', true); 
    $mpirate_array = explode(',', $mpirate);
    $url = esc_url( 'http://mywebsite.com/authors/' . $mpirate_array[$i]);
    $display = esc_html( $mpirate_array[$i]);

    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) { 
        echo $mpirate_array[$i];
        if($i < 4) { 
            echo ',';}};
        print "<a href='$url'>$display</a>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'authors_names', true);
$value_array = explode(',', $value);
$hrefs = [];
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $remove_space = str_replace(' ', '-', $value_array[$i]);
    $url = esc_url('http://mywebsite.com/authors/' . $remove_space);
    if ('' !== $url) {
        $display = esc_html($value_array[$i]);
        $hrefs[] = "<a href='$url'>$display</a>";
    }
}
echo implode(",", $hrefs);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `get_post_meta` method will return only one author because you set true to the third parameter, docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

To get only the first five results you can use the `array_splice` method that receives an array and you can set the limit of results you want to extract from it, docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php